# How can I getText for the first element of my String method?

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I have a String Split() containing two strings: one and two. I add it to a Linked list. Now I need to get the first element of one.

```
String split() {
one = ""; 
two = "";       
int index = tableFields.indexOf("(");
        if (index > -1){
        one = tableFields.substring(0, index);
        two = tableFields.substring(index + 1,
                tableFields.length() - 1);

        return "`" + one + "`" + " "+  two;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }

}


void readTextFile() {

    String line;

    while (FileReaderScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    fieldlist.add(split());  }
```

}

Comment: How do the strings look like? What do you mean by "get the first element of one"? The first element in the result of the splitting operation?

Comment: @Sorvahr yes exactly. now I need to get the value of one for another method. but it is empty when I call for it.

Comment: Split() returns a single String that either contains an apostrophe or an empty string. fieldlist I assume is a List of Strings, which makes it particularly unwieldy to use with your use of paired strings, which would serve better from a Class that stores two strings one and two, or even a list of an array of strings.

Comment: @Compass thank you. I think I now understand it actually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String yourString = Split();
int startIndex = yourString.indexOf("`") + 1;
int endIndex = yourString.indexOf("`", startIndex);
String result = yourString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```